# Doughnut pie hybrid d3 version 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an old doughnut hybrid pie chart/bubble chart combo working on d3v3.

[image]

//doughnut bubble chart v3
https://jsfiddle.net/ajevh5wf/

```js
var $this = $('body');

var w = 300,
  h = 300;
var radius = Math.min(w, h) / 2;

var svg = d3.select($this[0])
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .append("g")

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "placeholders");


var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.85)
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.83);

var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);

var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");


function colores_google(n) {
  var colores_g = ["#f7b363", "#448875", "#c12f39", "#2b2d39", "#f8dd2f"];
  return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
}


var data = [{
  "group": "<5",
  "value": 1000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "<5",
    "label": "Mel",
    "value": 1000,
    "totalGroupValue": 1000
  }]
}, {
  "group": "5-13",
  "value": 1000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "5-13",
    "label": "Erica",
    "value": 1000,
    "totalGroupValue": 1000
  }]
}, {
  "group": "14-17",
  "value": 2000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "14-17",
    "label": "Jessica",
    "value": 1500,
    "totalGroupValue": 2000
  }, {
    "group": "14-17",
    "label": "Jill",
    "value": 500,
    "totalGroupValue": 2000
  }]
}, {
  "group": "18-24",
  "value": 1300,
  "children": [{
    "group": "18-24",
    "label": "Jerry",
    "value": 500,
    "totalGroupValue": 1300
  }, {
    "group": "18-24",
    "label": "Ben",
    "value": 500,
    "totalGroupValue": 1300
  }, {
    "group": "18-24",
    "label": "Billy",
    "value": 150,
    "totalGroupValue": 1300
  }, {
    "group": "18-24",
    "label": "Billy2",
    "value": 150,
    "totalGroupValue": 1300
  }]
}, {
  "group": "25-44",
  "value": 1000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "25-44",
    "label": "Kelly",
    "value": 1000,
    "totalGroupValue": 1000
  }]
}];

$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  value["groupid"] = index;
  $.each(value.children, function(i, v) {
    v["groupid"] = index;
  });
});

//slices
var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
  .data(pie(data));

slice.enter()
  .insert("path")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colores_google(d.data.groupid);
  })
  .attr("class", "slice");

slice
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    this._current = this._current || d;
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
    this._current = interpolate(0);
    return function(t) {
      return arc(interpolate(t));
    };
  })

slice.exit()
  .remove();
//slices


//placeholder bubbles
var placeholders = svg.select(".placeholders").selectAll("g.placeholder")
  .data(pie(data));

placeholders.enter()
  .insert("g")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return "placeholder place" + i;
  });

placeholders
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + arc2.centroid(d) + ")";
  })

placeholders.exit()
  .remove();
//placeholder bubbles


//bubbles
function bubbledata(data) {
  //loop through data -- and MERGE children
  var childs = [];
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    childs.push(value.children);
  });

  return $.extend(true, {}, {
    "children": data
  }); // return deep clone
}


function setBubbleChart(width, index, data) {

  //_create bubble
  var diameter = width / 2; //take half/width

  var bubs = svg.select(".place" + index).append("g")
    .attr("class", "bubs");

  bubs.attr("transform", "translate(" + -diameter / 2 + "," + -diameter / 2 + ")");

  var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    })
    .padding(3);

  //_create bubble
  var data = bubbledata(data);

  var nodes = bubble.nodes(data)
    .filter(function(d) {
      return !d.children;
    }); // filter out the outer bubble


  var bubbles = bubs.selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes);

  bubbles.enter()
    .insert("circle")
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    })
    .attr('r', function(d) {
      return d.r;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colores_google(d.groupid);
    });

  bubbles = bubbles.transition()
    .transition()
    .duration(250)
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    })
    .attr('r', function(d) {
      return d.r;
    })
    .ease('sine');

}

//loop through data and for EACH children array paint dots.
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  setBubbleChart(100, index, value.children);
});
//custom bubble chart
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

//doughnut bubble chart v4 - not working
https://jsfiddle.net/4rdj0fze/1/

```js
var $this = $('body');


var data = [{
  "group": "<5",
  "value": 1000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "<5",
    "label": "Mel",
    "value": 1000,
    "totalGroupValue": 1000
  }]
}, {
  "group": "5-13",
  "value": 1000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "5-13",
    "label": "Erica",
    "value": 1000,
    "totalGroupValue": 1000
  }]
}, {
  "group": "14-17",
  "value": 2000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "14-17",
    "label": "Jessica",
    "value": 1500,
    "totalGroupValue": 2000
  }, {
    "group": "14-17",
    "label": "Jill",
    "value": 500,
    "totalGroupValue": 2000
  }]
}, {
  "group": "18-24",
  "value": 1300,
  "children": [{
    "group": "18-24",
    "label": "Jerry",
    "value": 500,
    "totalGroupValue": 1300
  }, {
    "group": "18-24",
    "label": "Ben",
    "value": 500,
    "totalGroupValue": 1300
  }, {
    "group": "18-24",
    "label": "Billy",
    "value": 150,
    "totalGroupValue": 1300
  }, {
    "group": "18-24",
    "label": "Billy2",
    "value": 150,
    "totalGroupValue": 1300
  }]
}, {
  "group": "25-44",
  "value": 1000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "25-44",
    "label": "Kelly",
    "value": 1000,
    "totalGroupValue": 1000
  }]
}];

var width = 300,
  height = 300;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#eb6383", "#fa9191", "#ffe9c5", "#b4f2e1"]);


var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 5,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  },
  width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select($this[0])
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'doughnutbubblechart')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var doughnutbubble = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'doughnutbubble');


var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

doughnutbubble.append("g")
  .attr("class", "slices");

doughnutbubble.append("g")
  .attr("class", "placeholders");


var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var arc = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.85)
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.83);

var arc2 = d3.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);

var outerArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

doughnutbubble.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


function colores_google(n) {
  var colores_g = ["#f7b363", "#448875", "#c12f39", "#2b2d39", "#f8dd2f"];
  return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
}



$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  value["groupid"] = index;
  $.each(value.children, function(i, v) {
    v["groupid"] = index;
  });
});

//slices
var slice = doughnutbubble.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
  .data(pie(data));

slice.enter()
  .insert("path")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colores_google(d.data.groupid);
  })
  .attr("class", "slice")
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    this._current = this._current || d;
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
    this._current = interpolate(0);
    return function(t) {
      return arc(interpolate(t));
    };
  })

slice.exit()
  .remove();
//slices


//placeholder bubbles
var placeholders = doughnutbubble.select(".placeholders").selectAll("g.placeholder")
  .data(pie(data));

placeholders.enter()
  .insert("g")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return "placeholder place" + i;
  })
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + arc2.centroid(d) + ")";
  })

placeholders.exit()
  .remove();
//placeholder bubbles


//bubbles
function bubbledata(data) {
  //loop through data -- and MERGE children
  var childs = [];
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    childs.push(value.children);
  });

  return $.extend(true, {}, {
    "children": data
  }); // return deep clone
}


function setBubbleChart(width, index, data) {

  //_create bubble
  var diameter = width / 2; //take half/width

  var bubs = doughnutbubble.select(".place" + index).append("g")
    .attr("class", "bubs");

  bubs.attr("transform", "translate(" + -diameter / 2 + "," + -diameter / 2 + ")");


  //var data = bubbledata(data);



  //console.log("data", data);
  ///

  var force = d3.forceSimulation();

  var foci = {
    x: 150,
    y: 150
  }

  var data = funnelData(data, width, height)
    .map(function(d) {
      d.foci = foci;
      return d;
    })

  force.nodes(data);


  var bubbles = bubs.append("g")
    .attr("class", "bubbles")

  var nodes = bubbles.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 1)
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
      return color(i);
    });

  // Update                
  nodes.transition()
    .delay(300)
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.value * (width / 6) / 100;
    });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    data.forEach(cluster);
    data.forEach(collide(0.1));

    nodes.attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
  });

  function funnelData(data, width, height) {
    function getRandom(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    var max_amount = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return parseInt(d.value)
    })
    var radius_scale = d3.scalePow().exponent(0.5).domain([0, max_amount]).range([2, 85])

    data.forEach(function(elem, index) {
      elem.radius = radius_scale(elem.value) * .8;
      elem.all = 'all';
      elem.x = getRandom(0, width);
      elem.y = getRandom(0, height);
    });

    return data;
  }

  function cluster(d, i) {
    var f = d.foci;
    var k = 0.55;
    d.y += (f.y - d.y) * k * force.alpha()
    d.x += (f.x - d.x) * k * force.alpha()
  }

  var maxRadius = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.radius;
  })
  var padding = 4;

  function collide(alpha) {
    var quadtree = d3.quadtree().x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    }).y(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    }).extent([
      [-1, -1],
      [width + 1, height + 1]
    ]).addAll(data);

    return function(d) {
      var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
        nx1 = d.x - r,
        nx2 = d.x + r,
        ny1 = d.y - r,
        ny2 = d.y + r;
      quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        if (!quad.length && (quad.data !== d)) {
          var x = d.x - quad.data.x,
            y = d.y - quad.data.y,
            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
            r = d.radius + quad.data.radius + padding;


          if (l < r) {
            l = (l - r) / l * alpha;

            d.x -= x *= l;
            d.y -= y *= l;
            quad.data.x += x;
            quad.data.y += y;
          }
        }
        return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
      });
    };
  }



}


//loop through data and for EACH children array paint dots.
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  setBubbleChart(100, index, value.children);
});
//custom bubble chart
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---bubblechart v4 working -
https://jsfiddle.net/of48xjar/

but when I try and add this bubblechartv4 code to the base v4 -- I can't seem to get the bubbles to render properly in the placeholders or the sizes -- and I think in the old version3 had to exclude the parent level to ensure it just renders children bubbles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things have changed from v3 to v4, like d3.pack() instead of d3.layout.pack(), and having to import the "ease" module and reference d3.easeSin instead of 'sine'. Once you take care of all these little differences, your code works:
https://jsfiddle.net/dc6eugtn/1

Here's the relevant section of changes:

```
function setBubbleChart(width, index, data) {

  var diameter = width / 2; //take half/width

  var bubs = doughnutbubble.select(".place" + index).append("g")
    .attr("class", "bubs");

  bubs.attr("transform", "translate(" + -diameter / 2 + "," + -diameter / 2 + ")");

  var data = bubbledata(data);
  var bubble = d3.pack(data)
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(3);

  var nodes = d3.hierarchy(data).sum(d => d.value);

  var bubbles = bubs.selectAll('circle')
    .data(bubble(nodes).descendants());
  bubbles.enter()
    .filter(d => !d.children)
    .insert("circle")
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    })
    .attr('r', d => d.r)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colores_google(d.data.groupid);
    });

  bubbles = bubbles.transition()
    .transition()
    .duration(250)
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    })
    .attr('r', d => d.r)
    .ease(d3.easeSin);
}
```

Comment: This replicates how it used to be -- https://jsfiddle.net/dc6eugtn/1 -- does it need to include the easin link? Also how did you change or control the size of the bubbles d3.pack(data).size([diameter, diameter]) does this limit the max size?

Comment: your version doesn't use d3.forceSimulation() or collide?

Comment: Yes, if you want the ease in, you need to include that module, as my fiddle does. I simply modified your v3 version to work in v4 as you asked, so I used pack with your actual data.

Comment: Why would you use pack and not force simulation or collide? like the bubble chart here https://jsfiddle.net/of48xjar/

Comment: also - how would you adapt to re-draw the chart if new data came in -- you'd have to fizzle out the bubbles, then reset the dognut chart and redraw the bubbles back - from a UX perspective.

Comment: That's out of scope. This question was about getting the v3 chart to work in v4, which I have done.

Comment: Why would you use pack and not force simulation or collide?

Comment: You used Pack in your v3 chart, so I kept it.

Comment: but force simulation/collide is used in the bubble chart here jsfiddle.net/of48xjar

Comment: why not use the force simulation/collide that was used in the bubble chart?